# Flow types as type "objects"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, flowtype

Is it possible to namespace flow types via JS object syntax, e.g.

```
type ModalActionType = {
  OPEN: string,
  CLOSE: string,
};
```

Which would then allow me to annotate via `ModalActionType.OPEN`.

Similarly, is it possible to mass-import a bunch of types via `*`, e.g.

```
import type * as ModalActionType from "./modalActions";
```

Can't say I've seen this done anywhere, but I'm hoping there are some flow config options hidden away that allow this.

Comment: You can use `$PropertyType<ModalActionType, "OPEN">`, but that's obviously not great.

Comment: are there multiple possible values for OPEN and CLOSE? or is it just a keys to constants mapping?